# No network on 2.6.36 kernel ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, linux-kernel

I just built the latest kernel from source 2.6.36 on my ubuntu 10.04 (fully updated)

The network is not working in the new kernel. Not working as in :

1. The kernel routing is perfect

> Kernel IP routing table
>   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>   9.126.134.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
>   link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
>   default         9.126.134.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

2. resolv.conf is normal
3. ifconfig output is normal

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:25:b8:f9:b5  
>             inet addr:9.126.134.128  Bcast:9.126.134.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::21c:25ff:feb8:f9b5/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:367 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:93 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:43922 (43.9 KB)  TX bytes:13364 (13.3 KB)
>             Interrupt:20 Memory:fe200000-fe220000 
>   
>   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>             RX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:3466 (3.4 KB)  TX bytes:3466 (3.4 KB)

Its just that any connection attempt is not going through. I am guessing that i need to 
upgrade some other packages also, but not sure which ones to update (from latest source) to 
get network working. I really don't want to upgrade to 10.10.

System : Lenovo t61p core2duo 2GB Ram, running ubuntu 10.04 / 2.6.32, wired network with static IP.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `ifup yourDeviceHere` and maybe `ifconfig` to your question? Also, knowing your system specs would help.

Comment: See my similar question and answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83972/ubuntu-10-04-lts-not-detecting-ethernet

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```
ifconfig -a
```

and see if there are other adapters (for example wireless), and which one is configured.

If you recall your last used IP address, or can guess a useful one, you can check and see if it is a startup configuration error versus a driver error by manually setting an IP like this:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig eth0 up
```

The IP address is just for example.